# What is the difference between a multi-dimensional array and a jagged array where all dimensions of the arrays are equal?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, jagged-arrays

I know that a jagged array is an array of arrays where the length of the inner arrays can be of any length.

With a multi-dimensional array, the inner arrays all have to be of the same length.

But if I have an array of arrays (jagged) where all of the inner arrays are of the same length, then what's the difference between this and multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 2):

Use of these two types of arrays, once allocated, wouldn't be very different. But there are a lot of differences in implementation and allocation.

**Allocation** It is simpler to allocate a multidimensional array. Simply:
`new int[4, 2, 3];`  For a jagged array, you'd need a lot more steps and a loop

**Implementation** A multidimensional is essentially stored in a single block of memory (or memory address space). With a jagged array, every sub-array is potentially in a different part of memory. This can have impact on caching and performance but the bigger hit is you get N indirections to access a single item, or a lookup for each dimension. For a multidimensional array, given the N indexes, the memory location can be determined arithmetically by the N indices. For a jagged array, you need a memory read for each index taking you to a new block of memory. A jagged array also has a lot more overhead storing the dimensions of each subarray, although it is pretty insignificant.

**Usage** for usage, really, the difference is more edge case checking. You can check the dimensions of a multidimensional array prior to accessing it whether the indices are within bounds. For a jagged array, to avoid throwing exceptions, you'd need to access each dimension one at a time to check the boundaries.

In other words, use a multidimensional array in this case. If you need a jagged array or it makes sense for you data model, then use it, but it is more complicated.